# Get only the record into records with the same day and near at 23:59 with linq C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datetime

this is my sql table:

[image]

I need to take a list with only one record per day, near at 00. 
For example the 2018-11-28 13:10 and 2018-11-28 13:03
I want to put in list only the record with 13:10 time.

Linq allow to get a list and filter the some day returning in list only the record near at 11:59 of the same day ?

i've tried with take:

```
List<HrpHistoryRepo> hhrListFiltered = hhrList.Where(x => x.HrpDateTime >= datestart && x.HrpDateTime <= dateend && x.HrpMccId == tmp.MccId).Take(1).ToList();
```

Thanks for advice.

Comment: The wording of your question is a bit unclear. Is the goal to group by day taking the last record for each day? And by 11:59 do you mean 23:59? You really need to clarify this question

Comment: @Nkosi yes i mean 23:59...i would get one record per day more near at 23:59

Comment: You wrote: "I want ... one record per day, near at 00. For example the 2018-11-28 13:10 and 2018-11-28 13:03 I want to put in list only the record with 13:10 time." 13:10 isn't near 00:00. Do you mean that you want the one that is NEAREST 00:00?  Which one is nearer to 00:00: 10:00 or 13:00? And do you want 10:00 to the 00:00 at the beginning of the day? And which one do you want if you have 11:59 and 12:01?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to group the records by date and take the desired record in each group

```
List<HrpHistoryRepo> hhrListFiltered = hhrList
    .Where(x => x.HrpDateTime >= datestart && x.HrpDateTime <= dateend && x.HrpMccId == tmp.MccId)
    .GroupBy(_ => _.HrpDateTime.Date) //<-- grouping by record date
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(_ => _.HrpDateTime).First()) //<-- get record in group
    .ToList();
```

So the above code first filters the records based the date range and identifier. It then groups the results by Date (ie the Day) and takes the record in each group  with the latest time (closest to midnight 00:00)